# Evaluate $g^{(51)}(0)$ of $g(x)=\int_{1}^{x^2}\left(\cos(t)-1\right)^6t^8\,dt$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Consider $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by:

> $$g(x)=\int_{1}^{x^2}\left(\cos(t)-1\right)^6t^8\,dt$$

Show that $g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and then evaluate $g^{(51)}(0)$

Since $f(t)=\left(\cos(t)-1\right)^6t^8 \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ basically because of $\cos(t)$, and since $g(x)$ is Riemann-integrable on every $[1, x^2] \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $g'(x) = (f(x^2))f'(x^2)$ is $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ in turn.

Furthermore $g^{(51)}(0)=0$, because we have that $\frac{g^{(51)}(0)}{51!}=k\,\,$ s.t. $\,\,k\in \mathbb{R}$ and $k$ is the coefficient of the $51^{th}$ grade term of the Taylor series of $g(x)$ centred in $0$, which is $0$ (as all of the odd grade terms).

Am I right?

Comment: I think the result is not Zero!

Comment: Is the upper limit $x^2$ or $2x$? The two situations are quite different in terms of even-odd symmetry concerns.

Comment: OK, so it's $x^2$, then yes, $g$ is even so all odd derivatives of $g$ at zero are zero.

Comment: @Ian  it is $x^2$ sorry

Comment: Thank you :) this is a good news

Comment: @Ian Please post an answer based on even/odd considerations, and put this to rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a discussion which shows at what derivative orders there will be nonzero $
g^{(n)}(x=0)
$.

Let $f(t)=\left(\cos(t)-1\right)^6t^8 $ and $F(t)$ its antiderivative. Then $g(x) = F(x^2) - F(1)$, $g'(x) = 2 x F'(x^2) = 2 x f(x^2)$. Going further, 
$$g''(x) = 2  f(x^2) + (2 x)^2 f'(x^2)\\
g'''(x) =  12 x f'(x^2)+ (2 x)^3 f''(x^2)\\
g^{(4)}(x) = 12  f'(x^2) + 24 x^2 (f'(x^2) +f''(x^2))  + (2 x)^4 f^{(3)}(x^2)\;  .\\
$$
I.e. the only terms which could possibly contribute to $g^{(n)}(x=0) $ are the leading derivatives of $f(t)$. Let's look at those.

Notice $f(x^2=0) = 0$, $f'(x^2=0) = 0$ etc.  We have to look for derivatives of $f$ which are not zero at $x=0$. 
Let $f(t)=a(t) \cdot b(t) = \left(\cos(t)-1\right)^6 \cdot t^8 $. Then by repeated application of the product rule, 
$$
f^{(n)}(t)= \sum_{k=0}^n {\binom{n}{k}} a^{(n-k)}(t)b^{(k)}(t)
$$
As $b(t) = t^8$, the only nonzero value of $b^{(k)}(0)$ appears at $k =8$ where $b^{(k)}(0) = 8!$. We have $a(t) = \left(\cos(t)-1\right)^6 = 2^6 \sin^{12}(t/2)$. That  means we need to take at least the twelfth derivative of $a(t)$ before we get $a(0) \ne 0$. So for $n \ge 20$, we have 
$$
f^{(n)}(t)= 8! {\binom{n}{8}} a^{(n-8)}(t)
$$
The mth derivative $a^{(m)}(t=0)$ will be determined, by repeated application of the chain rule, only by the one term proportional to $\cos^{12}(t/2)$ since all other terms have factors  $\sin^k(t/2)$ which make them zero as $t =0$. Since we need to generate this term by repeated differentiation of $a(t) = 2^6 \sin^{12}(t/2)$, we have that all $a^{(m)}(t=0)$ for odd $m$  since then no such isolated term $\cos^{12}(t/2)$ will occur. As $m = n-8$, we can state that for odd $n$, $
f^{(n)}(t=0)= 0
$.

Now let's return to the derivatives of $g$ which we started to evaluate at the top. It is clear that for all odd $n$,  $
g^{(n)}(x=0) = 0
$ since all terms will have factors of $x$. For the even $n$,   $
g^{(n)}(x)
$ will have a leading term with  $
f^{(-1+n/2)}(x^2)
$. As we have seen that these factors will become nonzero only at the 20th, 22nd, 24th derivative etc., we finally obtain that  $
g^{(n)}(x=0) \ne 0
$ will be obtained for all $n = 42 + 4\, k$ with  $k \in \cal{N}_0$.

For obtaining the value of $
g^{(n)}(x=0)$, let's look at the first nonzero case at $n=42$. From the discussion of the first few derivatives of $g(x)$ above, we have that $
g^{(42)}(x=0)
$ is determined only by $
g^{(42)}(x=0) = c_{42} \cdot f^{(20)}(t=0)
$. Now $
f^{(20)}(t=0) = 8! {\binom{20}{8}} a^{(12)}(t=0) = 8!  {\binom{20}{8}} 2^{-6} \cdot 12!
$.

The factor $ c_{42}$ is more difficult. We have to sum up the number of all ways to arrive from $g'(x) = 2 x f(x^2)$ at $g^{(42)}(x) = c_{42} \cdot f^{(20)}(x^2) + \cdots$. The following thought experiment helps in determining the factor. Set $f(z) = z^{20}$. Then $f^{(20)}(z) = 20! $ and  $f^{(n)}(z) = 0 $  for $n \ge 21$. So we have $g^{(42)}(x=0) = c_{42} \cdot f^{(20)}(z = x^2=0) + \cdots = 20! c_{42} $. On the other hand, with this setting we have $g'(x) = 2 x^{41}$ and hence  $g^{(42)}(x) = 2 \cdot 41!$. Hence $c_{42} = 2 \frac{41!}{20!}$.

Compare that by the same method, $c_{2} = 2 \frac{1!}{0!} = 2$ and $c_{4} = 2 \frac{3!}{1!} = 12$ as we have already established.

In total, we have $
g^{(42)}(x=0) =  2 \frac{41!}{20!} 8!  {\binom{20}{8}} 2^{-6} \cdot 12! =  2^{-5} 41! \simeq 1.0454\cdot 10^{48}
$.

I have checked that this result is indeed true by direct computation of $
g^{(42)}(x=0) $ with Matlab help.

Comment: This can be done much easier by using the power-series of $\cos(x)$ to see that $g'(x) = 2x(\cos(x^2) - 1)^6 x^{16} = 2x^{17}(x^4/2 - x^8/6 + \ldots)^6 = 2^{-5}x^{41}(1 - x^4/3 + \ldots)^6$. So $g(x) = C + 2^{-5}x^{42}/42 + Dx^{46} + E x^{50} +\ldots$ which gives $g^{(n)}(0) = 0$ whenever $n\not\equiv 2 \mod 4$

Comment: The function $g$ is even, hence $g^{(51)}(0) =0,$ so what is all this?

Comment: @zhw. The answer that $g^{(51)}(x=0) = 0$ was already given in earlier  comments. I found the problem interesting also for $g^{(n)}(x=0)$ for $n \ne 51$. So I worked on it a bit. See the first sentence in my answer: "Here is a discussion which shows at what derivative orders there will be nonzero $g^{(n)}(x=0)$."

Comment: @Winther Yes the power series of $\cos(x)$ does the job easier. I did it without power series.

Comment: @zhw. We also need that it is differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: @Andreas A sentence at the beginning explaining that would be good. The comment section is not for answers (although that is often done). As it stands, yours is the only answer and it doesn't show an easy way to get $^{(51)}(0).$

Comment: @md2perpe Sure, but the FTC makes that clear.